# how to create a simple pie chart using google api in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

i have a document library with 2 columns (Project title and Status) How could i make use of the google api and dynamically create the chart?

Should i use string builder to append to the google url or use javascript instead? Which is the simplest way to create the pie chart? Would really appreciate some code sample to start it off.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look here for Google chart API

[Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html)

also

[Adding Graphs, Bar and Pie Charts to SharePoint](http://wyly.wordpress.com/2009/04/24/adding-graphs-bar-and-pie-charts-to-sharepoint/)

For integrating

[Integrate Google Chart API Into SharePoint](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c16671)  [though its for sharepoint 2007]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the way of appending string to the page.

Although it may not directly related to your project, you can take a look how the [google chart work with asp.net MVC](http://blog.platformular.com/2012/03/20/load-google-chart-by-ajax-using-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Could you please provide a code sample of your suggestion?  The asker said it would be beneficial, and you seem like you know what you're doing so it would be much appreciated!